# usb: device descriptor read/64, error -110

Tags: usb

after this series of error in kernel

> usb 2-1.5: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci 
>   usb 2-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -110 
>   usb 2-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 3

this process (sadc of sysstat) or lsusb etc hang and stuck in D state forever

> root       2543  0.0  0.0   9812  1204 ?        D      /usr/lib64/sa/sadc -F -L -S ALL 1 1 - 
>   root     100998  0.0  0.0  22328  2116 ?        D    lsusb 
>   root      84710  0.0  0.0   5476   636 ?        D    modprobe -r usbhid usbcore usb_common

Q: is it possible to release it without a reboot?

fyi the usb is related to this virtual keyboard and mouse

> usb 2-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci 
>   usb 2-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=046b, idProduct=ff10 
>   usb 2-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3 
>   usb 2-1.5: Product: Virtual Keyboard and Mouse 
>   usb 2-1.5: Manufacturer: American Megatrends Inc. 
>   usb 2-1.5: SerialNumber: serial
>   usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
>   usbhid: USB HID core driver
>
> input: American Megatrends Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.0/input/input0 
>   hid-generic 0003:046B:FF10.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [American Megatrends Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.5/input0
>
> input: American Megatrends Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.1/input/input1 
>   hid-generic 0003:046B:FF10.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [American Megatrends Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.5/input1

Answer (score 1):

The problem cause was for the usb disconnect was a partial success, ideally it should be like this in dmesg.

> [2759033.084067] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: remove, state 4
>   [2759033.084080] usb usb1: USB disconnect, device number 1
>   [2759033.084082] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
>   [2759033.088425] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: USB bus 1 deregistered
>   [2759054.553007] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: remove, state 1
>   [2759054.553018] usb usb2: USB disconnect, device number 1
>   [2759054.553020] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
>   [2759054.553022] usb 2-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 3

Solution was to modify sysstat to prevent USB from causing the issue.

FROM:
`180:ub:*:0:a:32:p:8:USB block devices`

TO:
`#180:ub:*:0:a:32:p:8:USB block devices`

Then restart sysstat service.
`systemctl restart sysstat.service`